# How to make bones visible through only one object

Tags: armature, bones

when im working with a rigged object. I use the xray mode to make it easier to see the skeleton inside the object. But if i want the object (which in this case is a human) to hold something, like a weapon. Its kinda hard to see where im supposed to place the weapon in his hand, because the armature is in my way, because i can see the skeleton through the weapon. So how would i make the skeleton only see through for the human?

Comment: Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd> Z</kbd> in *Object Mode* and then go to *Pose Mode* watch [this video for demonstration at minute 5:13](https://youtu.be/5YT3Ocxeawo?t=313)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make object A always be displayed in front of B, but perspectively occluded by C in the current Blender.

The common practice is to create rigs (bones or custom shaped bones) that don't occlude by choosing wireframe shapes. A quick way to achieve this, is to set the **Maximum Draw Type** (under *Properties Panel > Object Tab > Display Section*) to **Wire**. The Armature will always be display as wireframe, making the objects "behind" it easy to see.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the older versions of Blender, but in 2.8 *Object Properties* for the *Armature* in the *Viewport Display* you can select the *In Front* option.

[image: "In Front"]